# What do you call an iterated flood fill algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, flood-fill

I have an algorithm that I'm using for my work, but I need a name for it.  I am curious if name exists in the literature for an algorithm of this type.

The algorithm takes a pixelated height map and a starting point s, and returns a modified pixelated height map.  For each pixel p in the returned height map, p is the value of lowest height you *must* pass through to get from s to p.

Example, consider the "peak" image in Matlab:  `imagesc(peak)` [image: Peak Image from Matlab].

And use the pixel (20,20) as the seed, then this modified height map I am describing looks like this:  [image].

I had called this a flood fill algorithm, until my colleagues pointed out that flood fills are typically binary maps.  So, Ive taken to calling this a "graduated flood fill" algorithm.

We have not found this operation defined in the literature.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you define "_must_ pass"? As I see it, you _mustn't_ pass by any particular pixel; you could always take a path around.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [watershed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)) to me.  Is that what you are doing.?

Comment: @LuisMendo It's the "heights" that you must pass through.  Every path from (20,20) to (49,49) must go down to at least 0.  Similarly, every path from pixel (20,20) to (35,35) must go down to a level of at least 0.8 even though the height at (35,35) is 2.1.

Comment: @chappjc It is very much like a watershed, except watershed (as I understand it) is focusing on segmentation.  i.e. labeling each pixel with a "region" ID.  I'm not interested in segmentation, I want to know these heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab, this algorithm is called [Morphological Reconstruction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphological-reconstruction.html).  The matlab command to implement the algorithm is called: [`imreconstruct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imreconstruct.html).

The specific steps are:

```
tmp = peaks
apt = zeros(size(tmp));
apt(20,20) = tmp(20,20);
imagesc(imreconstruct(apt, tmp))
```

which generates this image, as requested.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've worked in image processing a bit, but I've never come across an algorithm that does this before. So you can call it whatever you like, really. How about the "John" algorithm ;-)

Alternatively, you could consider calling it a "least descent" algorithm (or least descent *filter*, perhaps), since it effectively calculates the smallest amount of descent necessary to travel from one point to any other.

I'd avoid the word "fill" altogether, since it usually describes algorithms that are used to fill areas with a solid colour.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm has similarity to "distance transform" in that it is also about a path. Thus, "minimum descent transform" or "minimum path descent transform" may be an idea, since the pixel value becomes the lowest value one needs to descend to on the way to the seed point.

Comment: We have decided to go with "Gray scale flooding" but the brainstorming provided by both answers is much appreciated!